# Minimum number of attempts when knowing a probability

Tags: probability

I am confused as to which formula I should use in the following situation.

Say I have a series of independent events which can happen with probability $p$ (very small positive). I want to know how many attempts are required in average before such an event happen once.

Is it as simple as $1/p$ or am I missing something?

Comment: For your information. If $X$ denotes the number of attempts needed then $X$ is a random variable having [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) with parameter $p$. My answer is actually a smart way to find its expectation without using its distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "average" is denoted by $\mu$ we have:$$\mu=p\cdot1+(1-p)\cdot(1+\mu)=1+(1-p)\mu$$
leading to $$\mu=\frac1{p}$$

Observe that if at the first time there is no success (probability $1-p$) you start over with $1$ failure in your pocket.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mu$? Is it the number of attempts?

Comment: It is the "average" or more specificially the expectation of the number of attempts that are needed. In probabilistic language: if $X$ denotes the number of attempts needed then $\mu:=\mathbb EX$. Note that the number of attempts can only take integer values, in contrast with the expectation.